# Value of input field not retrieved : undefined object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML :

```
<table>
... some other rows
<tr>
   <td>
      <input id="Products_0__Quantity" class="product-quantity" type="text" />
  </td>
  <td>
     ...Some other columns
  </td>
</tr>
... some other rows
</table>
```

I have attached an event handler to a link contained in every row. I know it works,because other parts of the event handler function simply work fine. However this part doesn't  :

```
var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
var productQuantity = tr.children('input.product-quantity').val();
```

After this line, productQuantity is still undefined.

What's the problem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) instead of [`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/)

> The `.children()` method differs from `.find()` in that `.children()` only travels a single level down the DOM tree while `.find()` can traverse down multiple levels to select descendant elements (grandchildren, etc.) as well.

*Code*

```
tr.find('input.product-quantity').val()
```

Comment: I'll try, but that's strange because I am able to retrieve an hidden field, in another column successfully with children.

Comment: Edit : no you are right ! The hidden field is not in a column, it is directly in tr. Thank you a lot bro. I'll mark your answer as accepted in 10 minutes. I've lost 1hour on that and you solved it in 5 minutes.

Comment: @red2nb, It happens with even best of us.

Answer (score 1):

Please Try this:-

```
tr.find('input.product-quantity').val();
```

Instead of `Children`

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion something gone wrong in the definition of $(this),
are you sure about the element you get with $(this)?

however the .find() is better than children.